# How to convert .mxd file into .pdf file

Tags: java, pdf

I want to convert .mxd file into .pdf file. I have google under this topic but I ended with nothing. I want to know that can I convert .mxd to .pdf directly or do I need to convert using intermediate conversions?

any help would be appreciate.....

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Typically .mxd files are mapping files created with ESRI ArcGIS.  ArcMap has a tool to export a specific section to a pdf.

If you must do this programmatically (not by using a manual tool) you can do this I believe by publishing the MXD as a map service and then using the JavaScript, etc. APIs to make the conversions.

Answer (score 0):

well i found this

http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15139

Comment: this setup goes with ArcGIS but i want to do it using java program.